# Springboot Gateway Zuul

Tags: spring-boot, netflix-zuul

I have below props in zuul gateway

**Application.properties**

```
zuul.routes.product.path = /api/products/**
zuul.routes.product.service-id=dotcom-ms-products
zuul.routes.product.strip-prefix=true

zuul.routes.course.path=/api/courses/**
zuul.routes.course.service-id=dotcom-ms-course-service
zuul.routes.course.strip-prefix=true
```

**Actual MicroService - Rest Controller**
@GetMapping("/products/v1/getAll")
getProducts()

@GetMapping("/courses/v1/getAll")
getCourses()

Problem:
How can i access my services : I want the end url to access my services to be like

```
localhost/api/products/v1/getAll
localhost/api/courses/v1/getAll
```

But this is not working. instead i have to call

```
localhost/api/products/products/v1/getAll
localhost/api/courses/courses/v1/getAll
```

Note I don't want to change the RequestMapping at the services.

Comment: This example is helpful to you. [Zuul proxy example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52580597/auto-configure-routes-with-zuul-and-eureka)

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned  that you have common methods across services:

Try adjust your routing path as:

```
zuul.routes.product.path = /api/**
. . .
zuul.routes.course.path=/api/**
```

then map each different service per method:

```
@GetMapping("/products/v1/getAll")
. . .
@GetMapping("/courses/v1/getAll")
```

Comment: This will have issue when I try to test the service alone. We may have common methods across services and end having similar end-points

Comment: @Chala - sorry I missed your response, see updated answer above, hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I will show you gateway example.

**1. Create your service project (user-service)**

create application.properties file

```
# --- Spring Config
spring:
  application:
    name: OVND-USER-SERVICE

# Eureka client
eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: ${EUREKA_URL:http://localhost:8761/eureka/}
```

**2. Setting up Zuul project (Gateway-service)**

1.@EnableZuulproxy to tell Spring Boot that this is a Zuul proxy

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableZuulProxy
@EnableDiscoveryClient
public class GatewayServiceApplication {
```

2.create an application.properties file

```
# =======================================
# Gateway-service Server Configuration
# =======================================

# --- Spring Config
spring:
  application:
    name: gateway-service

server:
  port: ${PORT:8080}

# Eureka client
eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: ${EUREKA_URL:http://localhost:8761/eureka/}

zuul:
  host:
  routes:
    ## By default, all requests to user service for example will start with: "/user/"
    ## What will be sent to the user service is what comes after the path defined,
    ## So, if request is "/user/v1/user/tedkim", user service will get "/v1/user/tedkim".
    user-service:
      path: /user/**
      service-id: OVND-USER-SERVICE
    another-service:
      path: /another/**
      service-id: OVND-ANOTHER-SERVICE
```

**Eureka website ( localhost:8761 )**

[image]