# Auto-configure routes with Zuul and Eureka

Tags: spring-boot, netflix-zuul, netflix-eureka

Through reading various books / tutorials, it appears that it is possible to auto-configure routes in Zuul when using it in combination with Eureka service discovery.  That means that I don't have to explicitly add routes to Zuul's application.properties.

So I understand this correctly? Or do I still need to add routes explicitly to Zuul in order it to work as a gateway?

I would like it to automatically create routes from the application name's that are registered with Eureka.  Is this possible?

*(Note: I have actually tried this, but when I go to http://localhost:8762/routes I just get an error page.)*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure. In most microservices implementations, internal microservices endpoints are not exposed outside. A set of public services will be exposed to the clients using an API gateway.

[image]

The zuul proxy internally uses the **Eureka Server** for service discovery.

> 2. I would like it to automatically create routes from the application name's that are registered with Eureka. Is this possible?

Sure. I will show you gateway example.

**1. Create your service project (user-service)**

create application.properties file

```
# --- Spring Config
spring:
  application:
    name: OVND-USER-SERVICE

# Eureka client
eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: ${EUREKA_URL:http://localhost:8761/eureka/}
```

**2. Setting up Zuul project (Gateway-service)**

1.@EnableZuulproxy to tell Spring Boot that this is a Zuul proxy

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableZuulProxy
@EnableDiscoveryClient
public class GatewayServiceApplication {
```

2.create an application.properties file

```
# =======================================
# Gateway-service Server Configuration
# =======================================

# --- Spring Config
spring:
  application:
    name: gateway-service

server:
  port: ${PORT:8080}

# Eureka client
eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: ${EUREKA_URL:http://localhost:8761/eureka/}

zuul:
  host:
  routes:
    ## By default, all requests to user service for example will start with: "/user/"
    ## What will be sent to the user service is what comes after the path defined,
    ## So, if request is "/user/v1/user/tedkim", user service will get "/v1/user/tedkim".
    user-service:
      path: /user/**
      service-id: OVND-USER-SERVICE
    another-service:
      path: /another/**
      service-id: OVND-ANOTHER-SERVICE
```

**Eureka website ( localhost:8761 )**

[image]

Comment: One further thing: my setup was actually working - the only thing is that the "/routes" endpoint for the Zuul instance wasn't working.  It turns out it has been updated to "/actuator/routes",and needs to be activated by adding "management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*" to application.properties.

Comment: Also - I managed to getting it working using only Eureka, without having to add any route configuration to Zuul at all.  All Eureka client applications will show up in Zuul's "/actuator/routes".

Comment: Yes. Maybe this site is helpful to you.
https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/2726

Comment: Yes that's exactly the issue I was having.  I recommend anyone who finds this post, who is having the same issue to follow the links in that Github issue you posted. It explains the issue very well, and how to resolve it.  Thanks again Ted.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can integrate Zuul with Eureka and configure the routes based on application names registered in Eureka. Just add the following configuration to Zuul application:

```
zuul:
  ignoredServices: "*"
  routes:
    a-service: /a-service/**
    b-service: /b-service/**
    c-service: /c-service/**
    d-service: /d-service/**
```

Comment: Didn't get the point of defining an /x-service path. I don't wanna know which service exactly implements a rest endpoint. I want it somehow to route my request to it automatically